# Using the idiom "the other way 'a'round"

Tags: sentence-construction, idioms

I wonder if the phrasing within the following context is semantically correct or not:

> - Can someone tell me why my life is a disaster? Why **things always go the other way around to what it should be**? That's how my life... [(Source)](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.wattpad.com/amp/742053811)

I would phrase it as follows:

"Why things always go the other way around."

And to me, "to what it should be" sounds redundant.

What do you think?
How is it said normally in English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler would be:

> Why things always go the wrong way

or

> Why things never go the right way

It's not using the "going the other way round" idiom, but I think it's better not to use that here. The "other way round" is not normally considered an especially *bad* way, just a *different* way, and you seem like you want to talk about good ways and bad ways, so we would use right vs. wrong way here.